# Docker: Get host username from UID via shared PID namespace

Tags: python, docker

I am running a docker container with a shared PID namespace, and the container runs a webapp that displays running processes on the host to allow for monitoring. I am using python's `psutil` library to get the process details.

The problem is, for the username, the webapp returns a UID instead of username when it is run from the container. If I run it from the host directly, it returns the correct username.

Can anyone suggest what is the best way to get the username either directly or via the UID? I need to do this for all usernames not just my own and the number of users on the machine is arbitrary.

Comment: Add the user as that UID inside the image, or share the user namespace as well. Docker has no concept of the named users from your system so you'll have to map them up / tell it somehow if you want that.

Comment: @johnharris85 if I add the user namespace, I can't share the PID namespace. That is currently one of the documented limintations. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#user-namespace-known-restrictions

Answer (score 1):

I would set it as an environment variable and reference it that way.

EG:

```
docker run -it -e MY_USERNAME=$(whoami) alpine sh
/ # echo $MY_USERNAME
nick
/ #
```

Another way would be forcing the container name using a similar method:

```
$ echo -en "FROM alpine\n\nRUN adduser -S nick\n\n" > Dockerfile; docker build . -t example-name; docker run -it -u $(whoami) example-name sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine
 ---> 88e169ea8f46
Step 2/2 : RUN adduser -S nick
 ---> Running in f0ff1d5a75be
 ---> 916e94b7de6a
Removing intermediate container f0ff1d5a75be
Successfully built 916e94b7de6a
$ whoami
nick
```

However, this requires the user to be present in the image; the UID will **not** be consistent with the host or across systems.

```
$ id
uid=1001(nick) gid=1001(nick) groups=1001(nick)
nick@primestorage01:~/Code/playground$ echo -en "FROM alpine\n\nRUN adduser -S nick\n\n" > Dockerfile; docker build . -t example-name; docker run -it -u     $(whoami) example-name sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine
 ---> 88e169ea8f46
Step 2/2 : RUN adduser -S nick
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 916e94b7de6a
Successfully built 916e94b7de6a
/ $ id
uid=100(nick) gid=65533(nogroup) groups=65533(nogroup)
/ $
```

If this is what you are looking for, you should use [su-exec](https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec) in combination with robust config management.

Comment: I need the UID to be consistent with the host system, since I am trying to display the process monitor along with the user who ran that process. It could be any of multiple users.

Comment: Yep. Then you'll need to use su-exec.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the /etc/passwd file from the host in the container like this:

```
-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro
```

EDIT: You may even need to mount /etc/group too...

UPDATE: For jailing as a user (using `-u $(whoami)`), you would need to create another image copying the actual /etc/passwd and /etc/group.

Comment: That could be made to work, but it does have security implications. Further, it wouldn't work for actually jailing as user (eg: docker run -u $(whoami)) presumably because it's not mounted during the run command. 
Not saying it's wrong, just that it has some drawbacks.

Comment: You're right about jailing as user, though we may create an image containing the actual /etc/passwd and /etc/group files.  As for possible security implications, as long as /etc/shadow and /etc/gshadow are not mounted, I don't see any real danger.